# Elasticsearch multi_match and match is not working together

Tags: php, elasticsearch

This is giving me empty result

```
array:2 [
  "index" => "data"
  "body" => array:1 [
    "query" => array:1 [
      "bool" => array:1 [
        "must" => array:2 [
          0 => array:1 [
            "multi_match" => array:3 [
              "operator" => "and"
              "query" => "fac5762f-e332-41a5-b582-c952221dbfad"
              "fields" => array:1 [
                0 => "fs", "hcs", "id"
              ]
            ]
          ]
          1 => array:1 [
            "match" => array:1 [
              "oid" => "ae499e9d-8c9c-4d25-9f88-28f8fde64e10"
            ]
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
```

]

So, what I want to do here, first of all oid must be ae499e9d-8c9c-4d25-9f88-28f8fde64e10 and then check fac5762f-e332-41a5-b582-c952221dbfad is present in "fs", "hcs", "id" any of the field.

but giving empty result

Comment: If `fac5762f-e332-41a5-b582-c952221dbfad` has to be present in any of `fs`, `hcs`, `id`. I understand it has to be at least in one of them ? It does not have to be in the 3 of them ? If so, use `or` as the `operator`

Answer (score 0):

Your "*must*" clause forces the match to exist both with
"oid" => "ae499e9d-8c9c-4d25-9f88-28f8fde64e10"
and "fac5762f-e332-41a5-b582-c952221dbfad" for the fields "fs", "hcs", "id".

Wouldn't using *"should"* be better? That way if there is an occurrence in the "*match*" or "*multi-match*" you will have results.

Comment: I have tried should as well, but not working